# Event when npm package is installed?

Tags: node.js, npm

Im thinking of creating a plugin framwork in nodejs.

Can i catch an event when a package is installed using npm?

Comment: You can use ```npm``` [programatically](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm#using-npm-programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

you can add script to the `packages.json` that make something after and before install

```
{ "scripts" :
  { "install" : "scripts/install.js"
  , "postinstall" : "scripts/install.js"
  , "uninstall" : "scripts/uninstall.js"
  }
}
```

or add a hook script

`node_modules/.hooks/{eventname}`

see this example

[example](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples)

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking more in terms of a universal event emitted by npm when any package is installed. Something like a "packageInstalled" event that I could hook into with a function like "onPackageInstalled"

Comment: The only way to now when a packed has been installed is on this way, you don't get an event on node or other languages when a packed has been installed, what exactly you want to do, because actually the script that you put in the `package.json` run a script when a packed is installed